# how to show vscode metadata footer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to have this row at the bottom of vscode that showed nice file metatdata and branch information.

[image]

either an update removed this or I did something to hide it, any idea how to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

I must have disabled this you can enable it in the command pallet with 
`View:Toggle Status Bar Visibility`